# Recalibrating only the numerical index in a mixed associative and numerical array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In my program I send an SQL query to a table and it returns a resource which I use the function `mysql_fetch_array()` on.  The first argument is the results resource from the SQL query but if you leave the next argument out the default is to return an array which has both the associative index id and the numerical id.

This is useful to me because I'm using these results to create another query so need to have access to both the associative id and the numerical one since I need to iterate through this array which involves incrementing the number.  However, I have removed the null values through a PHP function and now I am left with an discontinuous numerical entries.  I understand that I can use the `array_values()` function to recalibrate my IDs but this eliminates my associative IDs from the array.

**Is there a way to only recalibrate my numerical ID's but not remove the associative ID?**

e.g.

```
'id' = [0] = '0001'
'gender' = [1] = null
'religion' = [2] = 'jewish'
```

I removed the null values, i.e. gender:

```
'id' = [0] = '0001'
'religion' = [2] = 'jewish'
```

Now I want to renormalise the numerical indices to:

```
'id' = [0] = '0001'
'religion' = [1] = 'jewish'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in function for this, however you can iterate trough the array to get the numerically indexed values:

```
$data = array(
    'id'       => '0001',
    'gender'   => null,
    'religion' => 'jewish',
    0          => '0001',
    1          => null,
    2          => 'jewish',
);

$num_keys = array();
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    if ($v === null) {
        unset($data[$k]);
        continue;
    }
    if (is_numeric($k)) {
        $num_keys[$k] = $v;
        unset($data[$k]);
    }
}
ksort($num_keys);
$data = array_merge($data, array_values($num_keys));
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't verified this but I think this should work. If not tell me and I'll delete my answer.

```
$i=0;
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
  $array2[$i] = $array2[$key] = $value;
  $i++;
}
```